# Что обозначают атрибуты name и content у метки meta?

Tags: html5

Что обозначают данные атрибуты у метки meta?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это мета тег для определения устройства с которого зашли на сайт, initial-scale - это маштаб страницы изначально, а width=device-width oпределяет ширину viewporta, подробнее почитайте вот тут http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport/

Comment: ,то есть это по сути масшабировка относительно любово экрана?

Comment: в общем суть уловлена верно, подключив этот тег можно уже работать с media-запросами в css под конкретные ширины экранов, будь то мобилка или планшет

Comment: Спасибо за понятное изложение ответа

Comment: тогда отметьте ответ как принятый) если что спрашивайте

Comment: сейчас так и сделаю)

Comment: о еще забыл спросить масштаб 1.0 это в чем?

Comment: Число с точкой (от 0.1 до 10).
Значение 1.0 означает что не надо масштабировать страницу

Comment: а строка content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> не противоречит себе, выходит страничка открывается в масштабе относительно экрана устройства и при этом не масштабируется?

Comment: [Ссылка на спецификацию.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#viewport-meta)